# mongo DB Balancing

Tags: mongodb

I have a collections with a shard key and index endabled. But when I run balancing, the chunks are not moved for this collections where as the other collection chunks are moving as expected to other machines. Only one chunk is moved from this collection.

Answer (score 2):

Currently (this will change in the near future), the balancer will only start moving chunks when there is a sufficient imbalance (8 or more).  If the chunk counts are closer than that, then there will be no movement.  The number of chunks is dependent on the max chunk size (64MB at the time of writing this in 2.0.x) and the amount of data written.  There is a split triggered every time a certain amount of data is written to a chunk.

So, if you are not adding data to the collection, or the data is not very large, it can take some time to create the number of chunks necessary yo trigger a balancing round.

You can take this into your own hands by manually splitting and moving a chunk:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Splitting+Shard+Chunks

Or, you can add more data to trigger splits and the balancer will eventually kick in and move the chunks around for you.

Comment: My data is very huge in terms of 10s of millions of records each record has around 3000 characters. And when I did printShrdingStatus it was showing that one machine has 2500 chunks and other machines has 1 chunk each

Comment: are there errors in the logs?  there should be if the balancer is failing to move chunks (chunk too big is a common one).  You may want to try some manual moves, see if they work.